# How to use symfony2 commands in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, symfony, composer-php, eclipse-pdt

I just switched from NetBeans to Eclipse (PDT). I am using Kubuntu 14.10. I really love it, but I can't get an important feature working: composer and other (symfony2) commands.

I've tried to run composer update (using [this](http://composer.dubture.com/) great plugin), but I'm getting this error:

```
[bundle] requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.
```

It's working in NetBeans, so it's installed. For some reason, Eclipse doesn't recognize it.

How can I the CLI in Eclipse, so I can run commands? That solves one of my problems and helps me finding out why Eclipse can't find the Curl extension.

**Update: composer is working**

I've installed `php5-curl`, so composer is running fine. For some reason that packages wasn't needed to run composer in NetBeans, but it is in Eclipse.

So part of my problem is solved, but I still don't know what the best way of running (Symfony2) commands is.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse does not necessarily use the same PHP that NetBeans used. Or the configuration differs. If that extension is reported to be missing, that's exactly what the problem is with the PHP you are using when running the command.

Find the location of the php.ini file by running `php -i` or `phpinfo()` (in a script on the command line, just like you run Composer) , and add the curl extension there.

Comment: But how do I run the command in Eclipse? When I run it outside Eclipse, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are linux/macports user, you have to enable "use system default php.ini configuration" in preferences/php/php executables.

Comment: I'm using Linux and I've enabled that checkbox. Unfortunately, that didn't help.

Comment: You also should cleanup "PHP ini file" box

Comment: This should be enough. On linux popular executable patch is /usr/bin/php , sapi cli, debugger xdebug.  Did you select valid (cli sapi)  php configuration in preferences / composer ?

Comment: Composer plugin may use cache for executables. Can you restart eclipse after set? :P

Comment: Yes, I've got that settings. I've tried to manually set the php.ini to /etc/php/(cli|apache2)/php.ini, but they didn't work either. I've restarted Eclipse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71722/discussion-between-zulus-and-stephan-vierkant).